# HTML DOM Parser in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

Using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parse but unable to get images to display.

I am not a coder and am trying to pull articles and images from a website. The articles are fine but the images are not displaying. Instead part of the path displays e.g.

```
> //ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/button/search-white.png
> //ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/button/search-white.png
> //ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/common/settings.png
```

Using Google as an example, here's the code I am using:

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_html('https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=in');  

foreach($html->find('h2') as $e) 
     echo $e->innertext . '<br><br>';  

foreach($html->find('div.jsdisplay') as $e) 
     echo $e->innertext . '<br>'; 

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
     echo $element->src . '<br>';
?>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: There is no such function `file_get_html()` in PHP. What are you talking about?

Comment: @feeela file_get_html() is from PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Comment: Ah, you mean the external project http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ not anything within the PHP core…

Comment: Change the last `echo` to: `echo "<img src=\"" . htmlspecialchars($element->src) . "\"/>" . '<br>';` - this returns [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img) tags, which tell the browser to display the image specified in the `src` attribute.

Comment: Thanks but images did not display. This is the code I used:
<?php 

include_once "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html('http://www.frielatvsales.com/QuadAttachments.htm');  

foreach($html->find('h2') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br><br>';  
}

foreach($html->find('div.general') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br>'; 

}

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {

echo "<img src=\"" . htmlspecialchars($element->src) . "\"/>" . '<br>';
}

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update my answer after your last comment with your original site URL** 'http://frielatvsales.com/QuadAttachments.htm'

**try below code.**

```
include_once "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";


$url = "http://frielatvsales.com/QuadAttachments.htm";

$html = file_get_html($url); 

preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $matches);

$host = $matches[1];

foreach($html->find('h2') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br><br>';  
}

foreach($html->find('div.jsdisplay') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br>'; 

}

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {

echo '<img src=http://'.$host.'/'.$element->src . ' /><br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Abid but unfortunately the code did not work. If you have any other ideas I would appreciate them.

Comment: you have add simple_html_dom.php class top side of your code.

Comment: i have added simple_html_dom.php class in my answer. please take a look.

Comment: you can download simple_html_dom.php class through in this url http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: I have this at top :<?php include_once("simple_html_dom.php"); ?>
The code is working for text but not images

Comment: this code perfectly working in my local system. i have update my answer. i have added output image please take a look.

Comment: Yesy Abid it is working on that Google site, well done. But it is not working on the actual site. Can you see if some change has to be made to this code please.
Here is the code 
<?php 

include_once "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html('http://www.frielatvsales.com/QuadAttachments.htm');  

foreach($html->find('h2') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br><br>';  
}

foreach($html->find('div.general') as $e) {

echo $e->innertext . '<br>'; 

}

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {

echo '<img src='.$element->src . ' /><br>';
}

?>

Comment: i have update my answer after your last comment. i have added new code. Please take a look and let me know if not working.

Comment: Thank you so much Abid. This is very good code and working very well.
If I need any assistance in the future will be glad to employ your services.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. call any time if you need my help.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

With

```
foreach ( $html->find('img') as $element ) {
    $img = str_replace(array("//ssl"), array("http://ssl"), $element->src);
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i ++) {
        $img = str_replace("//nt$i", "http://nt$i",$img);
    }
    echo "<img src=\"$img\"  /> <br>";
}
```

Comment: Tried that but images still not displaying. Thanks-Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`//ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/button/search-white.png` is a relative URI (the scheme is not specified, so it will use the same scheme (e.g. http: or https:) as the page it appears in).

Resolve it as you would any other relative URI.

> My question is how to get the images to display using the code in my original post.

You have to output an `<img>` tag instead of the URI as plain text.